# Update panel refresh whole page on safari browser

Tags: asp.net

> Update Panel refresh the whole page on safari browser not partially update the page.

Comment: can you explain more about your question. are you supposed to refresh your page with javascript?

Comment: explain your problem more in details then maybe people can be more helpful for you

Comment: @sajadre no it is an issue updatepanel refresh whole page (not partially refresh) on safari browser have you any solution?

Comment: Do you refer to asp.net web form update panel ? If so firstly I suggest to change your method for updating your pages . It is the feature of update panel asp.net web form if you want to refresh part of your page I suggest to use some client side methods and surely there is more help for you you can get better results.

Answer (score 2):

the code below can help you

```
window.location.reload()
```